# Loosing MySQL connections with c3p0 connection pool

Tags: mysql, hibernate, c3p0

We're using hibernate and MySql. We use c3p0 to create a connection pool. Based on my research, I've come up with these settings below in my persistence.xml file.
It is my understanding that the number of database connections should never go below the minimum of 10, and when the connection age reaches 14400 (4 hours) it will be closed and re-connected.

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="10" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="100" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="10" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="1000" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.numHelperThreads" value="30" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="14400" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="1800" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate" value="false" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3600" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery" value="select id from contact limit 1" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts" value="100" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay" value="1000" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.breakAfterAcquireFailure" value="true" />
```

Using this query I monitor the connections. I see that the number of connections starts ar 10, and for idle connections the processtime creeps up to 3600 and is reset, in accordance with the idle_test_period. But after a day or so, I check it again and see the number of connections reduced to 9. By the end of the week the number of connections is down to 6. When the connections reach 1, the program will lock up without throwing an exception when trying to run a database query.

```
SELECT 
    performance_schema.threads.PROCESSLIST_ID,
    performance_schema.threads.PROCESSLIST_USER,
    performance_schema.threads.PROCESSLIST_HOST,
    performance_schema.threads.PROCESSLIST_TIME
FROM performance_schema.threads
WHERE performance_schema.threads.PROCESSLIST_USER = 'loginname'
ORDER BY performance_schema.threads.PROCESSLIST_HOST, performance_schema.threads.PROCESSLIST_TIME;
```

As I said, the PROCESS_TIME goes up to 3600 for idle connections, but yesterday I watched one creep up to more then 17000, by the next morning that connection was closed and I was down to 5 total connections.

Is there something I'm missing here? Should the open connections remain at a minimum of 10? Is there something in these settings that is keeping the connections from staying open, or maintaining?

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely that you have a `Connection` leak, that is, occasionally your application is failing to call `close()` on connections that it checks out.

c3p0 in general will not interfere with connections that are checked out and under the control of clients. In particular, `hibernate.c3p0.timeout` (`c3p0.maxIdleTime`) will not be enforced, so eventually leaked connections will time out on the mysql side but remain forever in use from c3p0's perspective. Eventually, all connections will be checked out but dead, and new clients will hang indefinitely (unless `c3p0.clientTimeout` is set) waiting for connections that will never become available.

The only thing in your post not consistent with this hypothesis is that you have `hibernate.c3p0.max_size` (`c3p0.maxPoolSize`) set at 100, so you freeze when 100 connections have been checked out, not just 10, unless there is a server-side limit being enforced. But since you are looking at server-side open connections, the mapping between those and client-side open connections isn't clear, as you are only seeing connections that have been opened but not yet timed out. But I still find it very surprising if you never see more than 10 open connections.

Still, the first thing I would do is debug or at least workaround the connection leak. The main exception to c3p0's never-mess-with-a-checked-out-connection rule is [unreturnedConnectionTimeout](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#unreturnedConnectionTimeout), which you would configure as `hibernate.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout`. It will close Connections that have been checked out but not returned after some too-long period that you define has elapsed.

It's best, though, to eliminate connection leaks, not just work around them. Set the config property [debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces), which you would configure as `hibernate.c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces`, to `true` when you also set `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` and the stack traces that generated the connections that will never closed will be printed into your logs. Then you can try to understand the codepath that causes some connections to be opened but never closed. Usually it has to do with not using a `Connection.close()` strategy robust to all `Exception`-al cases. Post Java 7, the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) construct is extraordinarily helpful to address this.